# Suggestions for Designing UI for Grouping Search Conditions

Tags: user-interface

I'm building an advanced search page for my site where users can select a search category for a condition and then enter a value for it. A user can enter as many conditions as they want and each condition can be linked to the next with either an AND or OR clause. As a visual, this is very similar to what I'm going for: http://blog.lib.umn.edu/jeffryes/biomedical/Copy%20of%20Web%20of%20Science.png

I also want to allow users to be able to group conditions search conditions. For example, the Web of Science interface only allows these kind of queries:

```
a == apple AND b == 10 OR c == cranberry AND d == 20
```

However I would like my users to be able to do something like this:

```
(a == apple AND b == 10) OR (c == cranberry AND d == 20)
```

But I'm having trouble coming up with an intuitive and easy-to-use way to implement the UI to allow the users to group search conditions like that. Any suggestions or example websites with something similar that I could draw some inspiration from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this really depends on who your target audience is and how technical they are. Since you are describing pretty sophisticated conditional filtering, I'll assume that the target user is comfortable writing out logic.

I liked how salesforce.com implemented similar filtering in their reporting engine. As a user, you can add as many conditions as you like by clicking a plus sign (icon). By default, all of them are AND, however, you have a text field where you can enter the logic.

For example:
1. a == apple
2. b == 10
3. c == cranberry
4. d == 20
Conditional Logic: (1 and 2) or (3 and 4)

As stated above, this would make sense for a business application or somewhere in a consumer app, where the user has self-selected to be fairly savvy. It's definitely not the right approach if you are expecting consumers to use this without some advanced prep.